# Convert multiple tables from a html file to Excel preserving the CSS styles

Tags: python, html, excel, html-table

I have a html file and there are some tables, and I want to convert this html to Excel. Actually I can copy all page and paste it in Excel but I will have to repeat this process other html files. Can I use python for this process?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[tablepyxl](https://github.com/martsberger/tablepyxl) is supposed to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas in Python.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(html_file)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Comment: This file is not a table. Pandas see it as a list thats why "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'" @Irfanuddin Shafi

Comment: I want all css style colors stay the same style. It is not possible with what you wrote above.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's done. Hope someone answers. My script only converts html tables to excel.